# __autoload: Escape ClassName

Tags: php

this is my first attemp to create a frontController and I've come over some little problem.

**First let me give you an impression how my site looks like:**
When I open `http://mysite.com/test` in my browser, the server will call an index.php with the GET parameter $controller (test). This is done by a .htaccess.
In the index.php there shall be created an instance of the class $controller.
For this I use the __autoload function of PHP.
So the code looks like this:

```
$controller = $_GET["controller"];

function __autoload($controller)
{
    include("controllers/$controller.php");

    if(!class_exists($controller, false))
    {
        eval
        ('
            class '. $controller . '
            {
                public function __construct()
                {
                    include("404.html");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        ');
    }
}


$application = new $controller;
```

When you looked at the code I provided you may have noticed the **eval()** thingy in it.
I use this to avoid the fatal error when a $controller class doesn't exist, and display a 404 instead of it.

**And here starts the fun:** when somebody enters an url like

> http://mysite.com/ImATroll!:D

There will be

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!'

And...

> Fatal error: Class 'ImATroll!:D' not found

**So the question is:** How can I catch this? How can I escape the $controller variable a way that it only contains characters allowed for classnames?

Comment: first result in google for 'url validation' tells you how to do this

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/checklink
And how shall this help me? While a dot is valid in an url, it's not in a classname.

Comment: well, this is what I got for the first result:
http://phpcentral.com/208-url-validation-in-php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just throw an exception from your autoload function (p.s.: use [spl_autoload_register](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead).

This exception is catchable, so you can provide the 'default' functionality.

This is by far the superior method, but if you insist on creating this fake controller, you should be using class_alias instead.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply **drop** the `eval` part and at that part redirect to the 404 directly.

Or build *one* (non dynamic) `404`- ContentNotFoundController if you want, and simply use / yield that there (when the class name does not exist).

Comment: Sometimes life can be so easy!
I didnt see the wood for the trees, when following tutorial #30.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try `class_exists` before the call to `new $controller;` (class_exists will call the autoload function), and if false, include('404.html');

```
function __autoload($classname){

   $file = "controllers/$classname.php";
   if(is_file($file))
    include_once($file);

}
```

... but beware of the security issues - such as passing in ?controller=../htpasswd. You ought to sanitize the classname by removing all non-alphanumeric chars - like `$classname = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $classname);`

Comment: class_exists has 2 benefits here in my opinion:
when it includes a file where the desired class is missing, there will no fatal error happen.
And for the second of course the security issue you mentioned.
But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a class for classes that aren't found:

```
if(!class_exists($controller, false))
{
    $controller = "NotFound";
    include("controllers/NotFoundController.php");
}
```

You can also whitelist controllers that are allowed, and checking with `in_array()` whether you recognize that class name. The drawback of that is that you'd have to alter the whitelist for every class you add.

You could also write a regex that filters possible class names.